# Once ubuntu is installed, can I still update other operating systems?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, updates, uninstall, windows-8

Right now, I am a newbie almost ready to install ubuntu alongside windows 8 on my laptop soon, and have gone through most of the things I need to plan. Lately, I noticed that Microsoft is preparing Windows 8.1 as a free update to windows 8 users. What I would like to know, is when I install ubuntu on my computer, will I still be able to update windows to 8.1 (Same goes for other operating systems if I ever decide to install other distros)? I definitely will want the update to Windows 8.1 instead of Windows 8, so I need to know if I need to wait until 8.1 is released, or if I can go ahead and install ubuntu right now.

The bottom line is: Will I be able to upgrade Windows 8 to 8.1 with ubuntu installed on my system, or do I need to remove it in order to do that?

Comment: Close voters: This is borderline on-topic, and since it has good answers I think we should consider letting it stay.

Comment: @Seth +1. It's useful and practical information for Ubuntu users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An update should be possible. The only problem I can think of, is that Windows might overwrite your bootloader. In this case, you would have to manually reinstall Grub with a live disk to obtain your dual-bootable system. This process is explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384). [Boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) is a very-easy-to-use GUI tool to do this.

As it has not been released yet, no one can guarantee this. It would be best for you to wait a few day after it has been released and read some feedback of fellow Ubuntu users.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Windows 8.1 [will be available from Windows Update](http://www.techradar.com/us/news/software/operating-systems/windows-blue-update-to-build-on-and-improve-windows-8-1131737). This will not damage the MBR or boot loader. You can upgrade safely without having to worry about reinstalling Grub or fixing Ubuntu.

Comment: "This will not reinstall the MBR or boot loader." Have you tested?

Comment: I haven't tested. This is my source, it seems reliable: http://www.eightforums.com/installation-setup/30883-questions-about-upcoming-8-1-update.html