# If Windows 10 "upgrade" affects GRUB2 and screws up my dual boot with Ubuntu will I have to completely wipe my computer and start from scratch?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I turned off Windows update because I read about problems with BIOS tinkering within the updates. Partitioning is not something I do on a daily basis so fear has been creeping up on me with updates to Windows and Ubuntu. So to clarify, if the Windows 10 "upgrade" affects GRUB2 and screws up my dual boot, will the partions I created stay? In other words, if the Windows 10 update corrupts BIOS or GRUB2, is there a way I can check if there are partitions that have not been corrupted?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Comment: @Whaaaaaat how in the world a GRUB question addresses a Windows problem? What would you say if Windows actually don't touch the bootloader when you upgrade?

Comment: @Braiam Easy: When you upgrade windows, it'll reinstall the bootloader (it's done that for the longest time - I see no reason for Microsoft to change that policy). GRUB will be gone. You'd have to reinstall it to get it.

Comment: @Whaaaaaat aha? What if the boot path is UEFI > Windows | (GRUB > Ubuntu)? What if it's something else? You can't say that question will answer it, because **we simply don't know what will happen.**

Comment: I had ubuntu dual booted with windows 8. I installed a fresh copy of win 8.1 and it happened peacefully without affecting the grub menu. was a piece of cake.
must be coz i mounted the iso and installed from there. had i installed from a bootable disk the grub menu might have vanished
http://qr.ae/7dQ1AE

Comment: On Release version of Windows 10,  Grub bootloader was NOT affected, and I was able to boot. However something happened and Ubuntu 14.04 would no longer boot. So I had to reinstall ubuntu.

Answer (score 18):

Who knows? It's the best part of a year away.

The reason I'm answering this rather than voting to close is because even though we don't know yet, it doesn't really matter. Even if Windows Calculator deep-fries GRUB every time you use it, the answer is the same: **just restore GRUB**.

If you're going to use Windows, the most important thing you can know is to keep a LiveCD around and know how to look [for one of the GRUB reinstallation pages](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows) or  or a [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) CD.

Windows will always do what Windows wants to do, just learn how to cope with it.

Comment: [Will upgrading Windows 8 to 8.1 affect Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/360465/will-upgrading-windows-8-to-8-1-affect-ubuntu) Answer given here is though for Windows 8 but same can be applicable to Windows 10, hope that there is no major change with Booting part.

Comment: I'd vote to close this question as it is speculative and opinion based. As you rightly point out, no one knows what Windows 10 upgrade will do. It is not out yet.

Comment: We will know in a week.

Comment: I would bet at least $100 that it does, that's the Microsoft Way. I mean, some windows 7 updates (not upgrades!) broke GRUB. A whole new OS? I'd be shocked if it didn't

Answer (score 0):

Given that the boot loader for Windows 10 is new, it stands to reason that they will install it.  Technically, they wouldn't need to, but it is almost certainly likely.