# upgrade Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, bootloader, boot-repair, windows-10

in this moment I have windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04 and boot works in this moment. How can I upgrade my Windows from 8.1 to 10 with out destroy my boot between linux and windows?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Will upgrading Windows 8 to 8.1 affect Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/360465/will-upgrading-windows-8-to-8-1-affect-ubuntu)

Comment: Is system pre-installed Windows 8 or UEFI or did you install in BIOS mode? And if pre-installed did you have to do a work around to boot Ubuntu or can you directly boot from UEFI menu without issue? If you can currently boot from Ubuntu without issue, Windows will just make it as default and may turn on other settings in UEFI. Change those back and set Boot Ubuntu from UEFI or one time boot key. If you did a work around you will have to redo it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

If you want to upgrade to Windows 10, you'll have to reinstall your bootloader, since Windows will wipe it from existence.

To install the bootloader:

1. Boot the machine using a Live CD.
2. Open a terminal.
3. Find out the name of the internal disk by using fdisk to look up the device's size.
   For example:

   ```
   sudo fdisk -l
   ```
4. Install GRUB boot loader onto the proper disk (the example below assumes it is `/dev/sda`):

   ```
   grub-install --recheck --no-floppy --root-directory=/ /dev/sda
   ```

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126541/how-to-manually-install-boot-loader/126586#126586)

Comment: K then.... but do you know then how can I reinstall bootloader from windows? To obtain again my boot with all options.

Comment: @Vildnex Check out my edit